# Подсчет суммы из JSON элементов

Tags: java, android, json

Есть код получение json обектов, нужно подсчитать сумму всех элементов из получаемого, но не пойму как прописать правильно цикл.

```
StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, select_all, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("image_info_table");
                for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                    JSONObject info = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Item item=new Item();
                    item.setItem_name_Cart(info.getString("name"));
                    item.setImage(info.getString("path"));
                    item.setQuantity(info.getString("quantity"));
                    item.setPrice(info.getString("price"));
                    item.setSpinner_size(info.getString("size"));
                    array.add(item);
                    int sum;
                    sum=Integer.parseInt(info.getString("price"));
                    for (int b=0;  \\  ){
                     \\вот тут загвоздка
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
  ...
  sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(info.getString("price"));
}
// sum has the total value
```

Comment: Спасибо) А то второй цикл начал пороть)